# Are there any video games that are recommended for 6 year olds which might help development of cognitive skills and/or coordination?

Tags: video-games

I played some video games back when I was a teenager but never played anything since... I remember this as something addictive that took time away from what I now see as more important things. I now have a 6yo daughter. Should I introduce her to video games? I mean are there games that would help development / coordination? Are there games that are pure fun and can be introduced in a way which is not addictive?

Comment: Gaming is a very broad topic. There are of course games which would be suitable, such as Minecraft, Mario, and Lego games. It depends if she's interested. You would be wise, however, to look up parental controls on consoles or whatever games you'd look at playing, whether you want her to be able to go online, how much time to allow etc. As well as research into the games and their content yourself (for instance, Mario is pretty child-friendly, Grand Theft Auto much less so). Our 9 year old boy has been playing games for a few years and normally plays for an hour and a half a day, on Minecraft.

Comment: Please have a look at the related questions in the sidebar. Gaming comes up often enough that there are some good Q/A that might be helpful.

Comment: This question overlaps enough that I have closed as duplicate. BigEasy - it is worth having a good browse around the questions here before asking new ones.